# Can not install SPACY successfully

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I tried to install spacy though conda with the command:

```
    conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

The package was installed seemingly uneventfully. But when I tried to import spacy I got an exception.
It seems the module pydantic is not cooperating well.  I am a bit surprised that during the installation of spacy by conda no error message appeared.

```
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\_migration.py", line 295, in wrapper
    raise PydanticImportError(f'`{import_path}` has been removed in V2.')
    pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `pydantic.errors:ConfigError` has been removed in V2
```

In any case what should I do to be able to import and run spacy?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I directly installed `spacy` from PyPI, instead of `conda install` and it works fine.

```
python -m pip install spacy
```

Kindly make sure you are inside the conda virtual env.